# SciPy source code - cannot find an imported module

Tags: python, module, github, package, scipy

I am playing with scipy source code, [there](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/ndimage).

I am looking to method watershed in `ndimage.measurements`. Method is calling a mysterious `_nd_image.watershed_ift(...)` and module `measurements.py` does import `_nd_image`. However, I cannot find `_nd_image` in parent repository, and anywhere else.

I wonder if `_nd_image` refers to C implementation of `watershed_ift` in src folder. However, C implementation of the algorithm is not present in `nd_image.c`.

What is this `_nd_image` module? Where could I find this watershed algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion that it's in C is correct; [nd_image.c](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.c#L809) defines `Py_WatershedIFT` (exposed as [watershed_ift](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.c#L1013)).  This calls the actual implementation `NI_WatershedIFT` in [ni_measure.c](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_measure.c#L867).